# Android app with java ee backend

Tags: android, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

i'm asking if i can work with java ee and spring like a backend to developp an android application, also I wonder if I can execute an android app on iphone or it must be ios app to work on iphone thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

1. You can write Android app in Java or Kotlin. Java EE that is mentioned in your question is a platform for developing enterprise software, it's not related to Android app development. Keep in mind that you are going to develop an app for the phone, so the app should take as little as possible memory. It's better to avoid some practices heavily used for the backend development, for example reflection. That might slow down your app.
   If you need dependency injection framework you might be interested in [dagger2](https://google.github.io/dagger/). If you need http client you might be interested in [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for calling webservices. Also there are several ORM frameworks for Android - [room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) and [greenDao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/). There are much more frameworks, I'm mentioning only the most popular ones. Most Java libraries are suitable for Android.
2. You can't execute native Android app on iOS. If you are interested in multiplatform app development you can try looking into [react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)